# Unable to play the sample client to server streaming example in ASP.NET Core SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, nuget-package, asp.net-core-signalr, system.threading.channels

I am working on the .NET Framework 4.6.1. I  want to stream data from the typescript client to my service.  I have taken code from  [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/live/aspnetcore/signalr/streaming/samples/3.0).
This is the service side code :

```
public async Task UploadStream(ChannelReader<byte[]> stream)
{
    while (await stream.WaitToReadAsync())
    {
        while (stream.TryRead(out var item))
        {
            // do something with the stream item
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Client side:

```
const subject = new signalR.Subject();
await connection.send("UploadStream", subject);
// getting the byte data and calling next  in a loop. 
subject.next(data);
```

I  am using  ASP .NET core SignalR  library. These are the packages installed at the server side: Microsoft.AspNetCore 1.1.0 , Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common 1.1.0,Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core  1.1.0, Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.PRotocols.MessagePack 1.1.0

At the client side, I have the latest preview release.
"@aspnet/signalr": "3.0.0-preview6.19307.2",
"@aspnet/signalr-protocol-msgpack": "3.0.0-preview6.19307.2",

I tried searching for the right package to install for ASP.NET framework but didn't find anything. Is this functionality available for .NET Framework  4.6.1.

When I am calling the UploadaStream function from the client side.  I have received an error specifying that unable to invoke the "UploadStream"  function.
Please tell me the right set of the package to install.

Comment: [Event Streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/streaming?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is only available in ASP.NET Core SignalR. This is a completely different library from the old SignalR. The differences are described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-2.2). The two libraries aren't compatible and client code written for one can't communicate with the other

Comment: You *can* use the ASP.NET Core SignalR library in the old .NET Framework by installing the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR/) package

Comment: I am already using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR library as I mentioned